# How Kotlin Dispatchers works with non suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, transactions, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to the kotlin coroutines, where i need to know how the kotlin coroutine dispatcher works in specific case
For example

```
suspend fun executeDBTransaction(){
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
      executeTransactions()
  }
} 

fun executeTransactions(){
  transaction.beginTransaction()
   executeUpdateQuery() // non suspend function
   executeDeleteQuery()// non suspend function
   executeInsertQuery()// non suspend function
  transaction.successful()
}
```

What i need to know from the above example is that

> will all the query that i am executing in the executeTransactions
>   method will run on the single thread or not?

If my executeUpdateQuery runs on thread IO-1 and executeDeleteQuery on thread IO-2 then it leads to the unsuccessful transaction.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Complete `executeTransactions` will run on single thread with code .. And each method inside it will execute sequentially ..  How are you assuming there will be two thread ??

Comment: @ADM since it is executing in Dispatchers.IO which has  pool of thread. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/threading-models-in-coroutines-and-android-sqlite-api-6cab11f7eb90

Comment: Yeah exactly .. `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` will create a single co-routine and execute code inside it .. not multiple . unless you launch another one inside the inner methods ..

Comment: @Stack It will only change the thread if there is a suspension point, since there isn't it won't change the thread

Comment: @AnimeshSahu thank you

Comment: if you make executeTransactions suspend and wrap the function under coroutineScope{} call launch {} on every 3 function then it'll execute parallely into different IO threads

Comment: @AnimeshSahu then in this blog https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/threading-models-in-coroutines-and-android-sqlite-api-6cab11f7eb90 , they say even if the function is suspend which is under the pool of thread, each suspend function may execute in multiple thread.

Comment: @Stack it will if the thread which is suspended has been occupied by another task, since your functions are not suspending i gave you example about that. A suspension function like delay() may even change thread, but only when another task has occupied the thread delay was called on.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu it is sure that all the transaction queries in the example are executed on single thread?

Comment: @Stack yes, it will.

Comment: It is _impossible_ for the coroutine to jump threads without suspending. It is not just a decision that was made and carefully implemented that way.